# VBA code to move entire rows from one sheet to 3 different sheets based on cell values from dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use `VBA code` in order to move entire rows from sheet1 named "New Projects" to 3 different sheets, based on cell value picked from in cell dropdown list in sheet1.

I am not a coder but I could understand a little and fond a piece of code somewhere on the internet.

So far I found the code that can move a row from my sheet1 ("New Projects") to other sheet named "Prio1", if the cell value picked from dropdown list becomes "Prio 1" (meaning that I am moving that new project (entire row) to sheet "Prio1" because it has priority number 1.

But I have even the sheets named Prio2 and Prio3 where I need to move the rows when the value in the cell is "Prio 2" or "Prio 3", and I dont know how to do it.

If I just copy/paste same code in the editor and only change sheet names then I get some error message "**Ambiguous name Worksheet_Change**" and it doesn't work.

This is the piece of code that I found and it works for moving rows to Prio1:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim answer As Integer

    Dim lngRow As Long, ws As Worksheet, nextrow As Long

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("M:M")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "Prio 1" Then
            lngRow = Target.Row
            On Error Resume Next
            With ThisWorkbook
                Set ws = Worksheets("Prio1")
                If ws Is Nothing Then .Worksheets.Add().Name = "Prio1"
                nextrow = Worksheets("Prio1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            End With
            With Sheet1 'code name
                answer = MsgBox("Ska Almin flytta ärendet till fliken Prio1?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
            If answer = vbYes Then
                .Range("A" & lngRow).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Prio1").Range("A" & nextrow)
                .Range("A" & lngRow).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
            Else
                 Worksheets("Nya ärende").Range("M:M").ClearContents 'or do nothing

            End If

            End With
        End If
    End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

Now I need help to somehow add the equivalent code for "Prio2" anf "Prio3".

Can someone please help me out?

Almin

Comment: Sheet "Nya ärende" is sheet "New Projects" , (it's in swedish :))

Answer (score 0):

The error `Ambiguous name Worksheet_Change` means exactly what it sounds like (or what Google Translate would tell you it means --  *tvetydig* or *mångtydig*).

There is another procedure in your project that already has the name `Worksheet_Change`.

To find it from the VBA Editor, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and enter `Worksheet_Change`, click `Current Project` and use `Find Next` as required to figure out why the name is being used twice.

[image: find]

You'll have to either get rid of one of the procedures with duplicate names, or rename one, or combine the two together.

**A good tutorial**: [Excel VBA For Complete Beginners](http://www.homeandlearn.org/)